# Monitor Cloud Composer Airflow UI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

How to alert if cloud composer airflow UI is throwing server error?

Note: Airflow UI is hosted in Google tenant. I tried with uptime check but how to configure authentication for it. We are having multi factor authentication enabled in our accounts.

Can we use log based metrics? Please share steps for both ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, log based metric can be used to track the health of the web server.

Actually, Cloud Composer creates one automatically for each Composer environment. Its name is `logging.googleapis.com/user/$ENVIRONMENT_NAME-$ENVIRONMENT_LOCATION-web-health`. Naturally, you can setup an alert for it. Its expected value is >= 0.1 entries/s.